# Chrome focus on submit button by default after finishing the Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, dojo

I have a sumbit button, on click of which a AJAX call is fired. The Ajax call populates the dojo container present in the form. Chrome by default is putting focus on submit button after all JS processing finishes. I have posted the submit button code below.

Any idea how to prevent the focus on submit button after JS processing is finished. It is working fine in IE.

```
<a name="submitTag" id="ProductBtn_field" tabindex="-1" onclick="submitAction();"></a>
```

Code from submitAction function:

```
var deferedVar= dojo.xhrPost(XhrArgs);
deferedVar.callback(function(){
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
document.getElementById('ProductBtn_field').blur();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't the button be focused simply because you clicked on it? I guess you have to `.focus()` on something else to remove focus from the button.

Comment: I have tried too. It focuses on the other button but as soon as the JS finishes and page loads up, Chrome again focuses back on the submit button.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it in a fiddle? I couldn't see the issue, but I may have misunderstood your problem: http://fiddle.jshell.net/66mKa/1/